# Developing the mono application on Sharp Develop 3.1

Tags: sharpdevelop

Im testing the Sharp Develop 3.1 to find out that can i use sharp develop on windows for building mono application. building process works find, while i'm debugging ,execution is not stopping at break points.

Can any one tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in SharpDevelop.

If you compile your code with mono then .pdb files are not generated which are required by SharpDevelop's debugger. Running your code under mono will not work since SharpDevelop's debugger relies on the Microsoft debugging framework which is COM based.

I would take a look at MonoDevelop 2.2 which I believe has an integrated debugger that works under Windows.

Another alternative may be [Mono Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.go-mono.com/monotools/Debug.aspx) which allows you to remotely debug on Mono.